# How do disable Nginx file uploads completely or enable it only on certain locations

Tags: nginx

Is there a way to tell Nginx to completely discard file uploads (or the entire POST body) for certain locations?

Say I have a location block like so:

```
server {
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 80;
  server_name foo.bor.com;

  return 200 '{"foo": "bar"';
}
```

It's as simple as it looks like - Nginx always responds with a dummy JSON.

However, if the request to that endpoint includes a larger (10MB) file, the response from Nginx is substantially delayed (up to 3sec). I am guessing that's because Nginx still parses/buffers the multipart content.

Is there a way to instruct Nginx to ignore POST body completely?

Comment: How long does it take to transmit 10MB to your server?

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the allowed HTTP methods in that `server` block by testing the `request_method` [embedded variable](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables) and returning a reasonable [status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors).

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    if ($request_method = POST ) {
        return 405;
    }

    return 200 '{"foo": "bar"}';
}
```